# Alternative solution for "union all" clause in Jasper Report Print for HQL (Hiberante Query Lanuage) query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jasper-reports, hql

I am using Hibernate and Jasper Report in my application. For displaying results in jasper report i am passing a HQL query as parameter. In query i am using "union all" clause

as below

select a.bedId as BED_ID, a.date as FROM_DATE, b.transferDate as TO_DATE, a.bedCharge as BED_CHARGE
from HmsIpdGeneral as a, HmsIpdTransferDetail as b 
where a.mrNumber = b.mrNumber and a.ipdId = b.ipdId 
and a.bedId = b.fromBedNo

union all

select c.bedId as BED_ID, c.date as FROM_DATE, d.dateDischarge as TO_DATE, c.bedCharge as BED_CHARGE 
from HmsIpdGeneral as c, HmsDischargeDetail as d 
where c.mrNumber = d.mrNumber and c.ipdId = d.patientId 
and c.bedId = d.bedId

In above query i am collecting some values from 3 POJO files which are HmsIpdGeneral, HmsIpdTransferDetail, HmsDischargeDetail  by creating subqueries to accomplish desired output.

this shows me result from the first part subquery only(which is written before "union all" clause).

How can i write HQL query without using "union all" clause for getting values from subqueries as mentioned above. Is there any way to replace "union all" clause in HQL query.

What i need is combining result from two subqueries without using "union all" clause because "union all" is not working for HQL query to display results in Jasper Report.

Please suggest me alternative solution for "union all" clause which can be applied to combine results from two subqueries.

===== Editing =======

Here i am trying to make clear my scenario. Below are the 3 pojo file structure which i have. 
This application is for Hospital Management. i have to calculate the patient bed_charge and details for showing
which date to which date he was on which bed. If a patient gets admitted his BED_ID is enterd in HmsIpdGeneral table
and if he shifted to another bed then also values are enterd in HmsIpdGeneral table.

HmsIpdTransferDetail table keeps information about transfered patient and corresponding BED_ID.

HmsDischargeDetail table keeps information about discharged patient and corresponding vaccant BED_ID

I have to display the details of the patient that from which date to which date he was on which BED_ID and
have to show the BED_CHARGE.

Here is the POJO file structure (for convenience i have removed non-useful fields from the structure )

HmsIpdGeneral Table Structure  // Keeps information of BED_ID that on which date which bed is allotted to whom

```
 private Integer id;
 private String mrNumber;
 private String ipdId;    
 private String bedId;    // for BED_ID
 private double bedCharge;  // for BED_CHARGE
 private Date date;   // for FROM_DATE
```

HmsIpdTransferDetail Table Structure  // Keeps information of patient transfered to another BED_ID

```
 private Integer transferId;
 private String mrNumber;
 private String ipdId;
 private String fromWardCode;
 private String toWardCode; 
 private String fromBedNo;  // for BED_ID from where patient is transfered
 private String toBedNo;    // for NEW BED_ID where patient is transfered 
 private Date transferDate; // for TO_DATE
```

HmsDischargeDetail Table Structure // Keeps information of patient discharge and BED_ID status will become vaccant

```
 private String mrNumber;
 private String patientId; // ipdId will be inserted here    
 private String bedId; // for BED_ID where patient is last time shifted before discharge
 private Date dateAdmission;
 private Date dateDischarge;   // for TO_DATE
```

Jasper Report Structure for specific MrNumber and IpdId (which is performed by using query)

BED_ID   ||  FROM_DATE   ||  TO_DATE  ||  BED_CHARGE

For getting above Result i have mentioned my query. what can be the other way to get desired output.

i thanks to all valuable suggestion.

Comment: First of all your question is unreadable. Please format your code in a sane manner. And second you need to indicate the mapping of your classes. Help us understand your question Toman

Comment: Thanks for comment. I need an alternative solution for "union all" clause for combining results of two subqueries. The query will be supplied as parameter to jasper report.

Comment: And what about the part where we cannot read your code because it is unformatted? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: It doesn't look like your entities are mapped to each other. Are they? If so you need to indicate the mapping.

Comment: There is no mapping entities for above 3 hbm xml files.

Comment: Hibernate expects your entities to be mapped.

Comment: If i perform mapping and replace two subqueries with single subquery that will affect other part of my application, hence making change in mapping is not feasible for me.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot understand your use case. If you cannot map your classes what is the point of using Hibernate? Just use SQL.

Comment: If this is the only solution then i'll look for it.
But still i expect some better solution for "union all" clause alternative, hence i am not closing the question. Thanks carbontax.